# Heroku performance vs local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, heroku

I'm running a ruby on Rails service. Ruby 2.0 and rails 4.0 The job on heroku takes ~2x the time it does on my local machine.  I would expect the processing elements to actually run faster on the big *#!# server than on my macbook air.

sorry for the lousy formatting  Times are in seconds 1.00000

```
                                                   Herok Macbook Air delta
```

1. job_id=Job.where(id:user.id, active:true).pluck(:id)[0]___t1=0.003 _*t2= 0.126*_delta=0.123
2. {job Prep}***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**_t1= 0.00_t2=0.00_delta=0.00
3. imagedata=Jobimage.find_by(job_id: job_id, level:0)***_*__** t1=0.349 t2=0.044 delta=0.305
4. image=Marshal.load(imagedata.data)  ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__***t1=0.374  t2=0.096    delta= 0.278***_**
5. Job processing  ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***_t1= 0.51  t2=0.328    delta=0.182
6. render json:answer.to_s_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**_t1=0.51 t2=0.328    delta0.182

Except for the Job -processing block, these are statements bracketed by logging statements

I'm really surprised by 4 and 6

Can anyone explain why Heroku would be getting the stuffing kicked out of it my my notebook

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're one of many (hundreds? thousands?) of people sharing that physical box, and Heroku has no incentive to make your code *fast* for a free instance. Your Macbook Air is doing (more or less) *one thing*.

Comment: A Heroku 1X dyno is 512 MB and '1X CPU Share', i.e. less than a CPU. I'd assume even your Air has more punch than that. Spring for a PX dyno and you'll probably see different results...

Comment: I guess so, but the PX dyno isn't any faster, tied it out just to check.

Comment: Okay i did some more timings.  First, brain dead on my part, i overlapped the Marshal load with the db call, saves a chunk of time.  But as far as i can tell, the other time seems to be caused by something else holding off the render process.  If i run a test just doing the .to_s or .to_json, it's fast, so i'm guessing something in the job processing block has to finish before the render can complete.  I'll look into that now.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem. Judging by the things you have timed in your breakdown, I don't think it will apply directly to what you are trying to accomplish, but it might be useful in a different part of your project.

Comment: I am using delayed_job.  It's great, i've offloaded everything I can, this is one of the has to be realtime tasks that i have.